# How to speed up scapy sending packets speed at layer 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, scapy

I‘m writing an anonzmized penetration testing tool for Dos-sing and I my question is how can I speed up its packet sending rate at layer 3. At layer 2 I know what I have to do but need help please.

Comment: If you know what to do in layer 2- why don't you just send the packets in layer 2? (add an Ethernet layer and send the packet using `sendp` instead of `send`)

Comment: @ shir Because I don’t have Ethernet on my computer